# Compiling java code with shellscript, including several files(.jars .class)

Tags: java, shell, batch-file, compilation, javac

I have the following code to compile a java program in shellscript:

```
javac workshop/*.java -cp jars/\*  
javac menu/*.java -cp jars/\*  -cp workshop/
```

This code should compile everything java file in workshop and include everything in jars and then it should compile everything in menu while including every jar file in jars and every .class file in workshop.

However it's not as the second command gives me the error

```
menu/PgElementSet_Menu.java:15: error: package workshop does not exist
import workshop.*;
```

the package workshop is in the workspace.MyWorkShop.class (amongst others).

Now I'm probably doing somethign stupid but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, the code is based on a .bat files which does the following (and works on windows machines)

```
javac -classpath jars\javaview.jar;jars\jvx.jar;. workshop\*.java
javac -classpath jars\javaview.jar;jars\jvx.jar;. menu\*.java
@pause
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you don't need `\*` here: `-cp jars/\* `. Also, I'd follow precedence specified in the `javac` man page: `javac [ options ] [ sourcefiles ] [ classes ] [ @argfiles ]`, i.e. `javac -cp jars workshop/*.java`

Comment: javac -cp jars workshop/*.java doesn't work and throws a massive number of missing package errors. (missing jars probably)

Comment: whats the output directory of class files for `workshop`

Comment: @Sanjeev The first .command sends a number of .class files to the workshop folder (workshop/MyWorkshop.class from workshop/MyWorkshop.java)

Comment: try with slashes instead of backslashes - `menu/*.java`

Comment: @npocmaka I have slahes rather then backslashes in the .sh code right (the top one)?

Comment: menu and workshop are java packages ??

Comment: @Sanjeev in this case they are, however it's possible that there are more packages somewhere in there

Comment: @Thijser Please see my answer

Comment: Offtopic:The workshop must cover bit of build tools such as ant or gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shall work for you

```
for i in `ls jars/*.jar`; 
do 
    export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$i; 
done
export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH
javac `find * -name *.java`
```